# Topology on $\Bbb R^n\cup \{\infty\}$ compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Suppose you have the set $\Bbb R^n\cup \{\infty\}$. Define the topology on this set to include all regular open balls in $\Bbb R^n$ as well as sets of the form $\{x\in\Bbb R^n \mid |x|>r\}\cup \{\infty\}$ for any $r$. How would you show that $X$ is compact? I know I should take an arbitrary cover and turn it into a finite subcover, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Starting your subcover with one open set containing infinity, what is left to cover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a cover of $X=\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$ and let $U_{\infty}\in\mathcal{U}$ s.t. $\infty\in U_{\infty}$. Then $X\backslash U_{\infty}$ is a closed bounded set, hence compact. The family of open sets $\mathcal{U}\backslash \{ U_{\infty} \}$ is a cover of $X\backslash{U_{\infty}}$, thus it has a finite subcover $\mathcal{U}'$. Then $\mathcal{U}'\cup\{ U_{\infty}\}$ is a finite subcover of $\mathcal{U}$.